# Get keyboard to disappear when clicking outside of searchview

Tags: android, android-activity, keyboard, searchview, listeners

I'm currently stuck on trying to make the keyboard disappear when I click outside of the searchview tab.

My issue is that I tried to attach a onfocus change listener to the topmost layout to clear focus from the searchview when clicked outside, and while it works, the listener only works up until slightly below the progress bar. I can't get the listner to cover the whole screen. Help? I've tried to get the top most layout's parent and that hasn't worked.

Here is a picture of my screen showing up until where the listener works too: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Dd6tnM1aneaUVZNTI1NXQydDA/view?usp=sharing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/session_linear_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/Session_searchbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/session_progress_spinner"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >
    </ProgressBar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = 
        (InputMethodManager) context.
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
        searchView.getWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: I have that code right now, im just not sure where to put it since putting it in the parent layout, it only works up to around the middle of the screen

Comment: use `OnTouchListener` on the `LinearLayout` and dismiss it on `MOVE_UP`

Comment: I did that already, but the ontouch listener only works up to the progressBar and not below it. Che k o

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` does not have any height? What is the height of it?